# Default value in html select

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

Hi I hava a question how to set default value ex.30 in html select in jinja 2

The code is following:

```
<select name="cmo_etc">
    {% for i in range(1,13): %}
    <option {% if set_etc == (i*5) %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ i*5 }}">
         {{ i*5 }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The code works fine but default value is 5. I need to change it to another value ex.30

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I would try simply checking the `i` index variable

```
{% for i in range(1,13): %}
   <option {% if i == 6 %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ i*5 }}">
   {{ i*5 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

when `i == 6` your value attribute is 30

Answer (score 0):

The `set_etc` variable is the default value in your case. Change that to 30 or whatever you want.